# Warning onRowClick is deprecated

Tags: html, angular, reactjs, nodes, antd

using ant design am adding function on dynamic table component but getting Warning in console

> Warning onRowClick is deprecated

so if any one know solution please help
thanks

Comment: Use `onRow` instead?

Answer (score 3):

If you are still getting this issue:

> Warning: onRowClick is deprecated, please use onRow instead.

You can fix it by going from this:

```
onRowClick={(record) => ({ 
  onClick: () => { this.someClick(record.key) } 
})}
```

To this:

```
onRow={(record) => ({ 
  onClick: () => { this.someClick(record.key) } 
})}
```

Comment: @Elizbeth What did you *think* the message meant, if not this?